# What modal verbs do natives use nowadays?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

We are being taught English by a native speaker from Alaska. He states that many of modal verbs we were taught are outdated and have been replaced.

E.g.:

> - We must ➙ We have to
> - May I come in? ➙ Do you mind if I come in?
> - We don't have to leave yet. ➙ We don't gotta go yet.

Totally outdated: "ought to" and "shall".

Is it true, and if so, to what extent? Which modal verbs do you regularly use in your spoken English and which in written language?

Comment: Interesting question, although I doubt very much that the third example is in common use in the UK.

Comment: to Frank: I appreciate, if you can say how does someone ask permission in the UK?

Comment: The second example (both versions) would be normal in the UK for asking permission "May I .... " or "Do you mind if I ..." or "Is it OK for me to ..." or "I would like to ...., if that's alright with you".

Comment: Yes. Wouldn't a native speaker come from where the language was developed? Whilst the advisor makes a valid point, the usage of various modals is idiosyncratic and a function of region. British English is not fixed, but is moving away from traditional modal constructions far more slowly than American English. And the choice between 'we must' and 'we have to', say, would usually depend heavily on context, at least in the UK. 'We must go and see Aunt Sally soon' 'We have to finish our assignment by next Thursday'.

Comment: This all applies only to US English: _Have to_ is still very common and is in no way outdated or replaced. _Must_ and _may_ are also still used, but only rarely in their originally most basic meanings. Now they're mainly used in cases like “You must be new here!” and “You may want to have a look at this”. _Ought to_ is still quite common at least with some verbs (“you ought to/oughta know that…”, for example). _Shall_ is fairly dead in colloquial US English, but it's still used by some in British English.

Comment: Also, your teacher seems to be contradicting himself. He is saying that _must_ is replaced by _have to_, but _have to_ is replaced by _got to/gotta_?!

Comment: Edwin Ashworth: At school we were taught, that MUST is very strong word. Like "Whatever it takes, I must clean my room today." If you say "I have to" - it's not a must - might do, might postpone and watch TV instead.

Comment: @Denis, that's not correct. _Have to_ is just as strong as _must_. If you're looking for something weaker, you should be looking at _should_ or _ought to_.

Comment: to Janus Bahs Jacquet: He meant "gotta" replaces "have to" in this very context, not in general.

Comment: @ user1065145 We were taught to use the dictionary. Mind you, today there are [much better ones](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/must). And for 'have to + infinitive': to be compelled, obliged, or required —used with an infinitive with to or to alone <we had to go> <do what you have to> <it has to be said> [M-W]

Comment: to Janus Bahs Jacquet: Thanks for clarification! So I can still use should for weaker obligation. I am frequently being asked on how to use some Engish grammatical structures and would like to give people some trusted information so that they don't make fun out of themselves when speak)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - You know much more about languages than I do, but you seem to have an exaggerated view of the disintegration of American English. Bad English is bad English in the United States as well as elsewhere. If one of my kids (all adults) said *We don't gotta go yet*, I guarantee you, it would stop me dead in my tracks, and I would wonder if my child was suffering a TIA. Once I was assured of their neurological health, I would fix upon them a stare such as they have not seen in a decade. Luckily, they will *never* say that.

Comment: @medica, oh yes—“We don't gotta” is at best _very_ informal and colloquial in any dialect (and quite ungrammatical in most); my restriction to AmE above was mostly that some modals (like _must_ and _shall_) are still fairly commonplace in BrE, but not AmE except in certain constructions and semantic subsets. “You must show me that little cafe you like so much sometime” is quite normal in BrE, but would be marked as formal in AmE where “You'll have to show me…” would be the more neutral form.

Comment: The most highly qualified contributor here (unless I'm mistaken) goes as far as using 'sposta'. Of course, we can stone him to death if it's not in general use in 200 years.

Comment: @Janus **except in certain constructions and semantic subsets**. That's a synonym for English.

Comment: @medica I'd have corrected my son (before he started the body-building) for using 'He got accepted at Leeds University'. I'd have disowned him for 'We don't gotta go yet'. But I suspect you wouldn't bat an eyelid at the former.

Comment: to Edwin Ashworth: How "He got accepted at Leeds University" should be told correctly?

Comment: @Edwin, not really. _Must_ in colloquial AmE is largely confined to the sense of expressing something that is logically very likely; the deontic sense is not common in informal speech. This is not true of BrE. Similarly, the permissive senses of _may_ are rarely found in AmE, but common in BrE. That’s why I limited my initial comment to describing current AmE usage: there are differences. Since the teacher mentioned in the question is American, I described AmE rather than BrE.

Comment: @Denis, the more traditional way to make a passive in English is with the auxiliary verb _to be_: “He was accepted”, rather than “He got accepted”.

Comment: Wow! I was thinking more about omitting have here ("He <have> got accepted at Leeds University") but even to me it seemed way too bound to formal rules. Tnx for clarifying!

Comment: @Janus I'm saying 'except in certain constructions and semantic subsets' is a fair definition of the English language.

Comment: @Denis I'm a lot more relaxed about using the get-passive nowadays. It's never been a total taboo; 'They're getting married' has always been quite acceptable. It's useful to have a disambiguator for sentences like 'The window was broken' [is that punctive or stative?]. But I avoid 'get' where possible on stylistic (ie what I prefer!) grounds: 'He was accepted ...' is unambiguous.

Comment: English is a permissive language that allows speakers much flexibility, but "don't gotta go" is out of bounds. Besides that, I doubt these tips would be any good once you leave Alaska. Certainly, not in my neck of the woods (couldn't resist this one). My tip would be: stay with standard English (BBC, CNN, CNBC or something like that). The risk if you try to speak like a rapper (besides getting roughed up), is you'll wind up saying absurd things like "I wanna to" or "I gotta to".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and others - it may be worth noting that "native", in an Alaskan context, very likely refers to his membership within an indigenous people group.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy **Not here.** Google has: **na·tive speak·er**
noun
1.
a person who has spoken the language in question from earliest childhood.
"native speakers of English" >> The compound noun usage would almost always be inferred here (otherwise we have to ask what is meant by the noun 'speaker' here – someone who's on his soap-box when not teaching?)

Comment: "We must" is much rarer in American English (AmE) than British English (BrE), but you will still be understood. "May I come in?" is quite formal, and might be too stiff and stodgy in most informal situations, but it's legal. "We don't have to leave yet" would often be "We don't have to go yet." Agreed that "ought to" and "shall" are very rare in AmE, but still used in BrE.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I use "shall" regularly in the US.  It's like a more forceful version of "should", and rolls off the tongue much more easily for some phrases.

Comment: @Izkata Give us examples of those phrases, please!

Comment: @DenisKulagin First off the top of my head is a simple "Shall we go now?" when random conversations happen instead of going somewhere (to lunch as a group, for example).  'Tis not enough for a full answer, though.

Comment: @Izkata Great example! It sounds natural even to me.

Comment: @Izkata, good example! I hadn't thought about that. Apart from “shall we?” and its variations, though, I wouldn't use it—certainly not as a simple future as in BrE (“I shall be a bit late” or “I shan't say a word”, for example, sound frightfully hoity-toity and stilted to me in AmE).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question is to some extent a matter of opinion. However, I would say that your examples are not examples which are widely considered outdated, **especially** in written English.

*We must* is used in formal speech and in writing. In informal speech, it has been largely replaced by *we need to*, *we have to* and *we've got to*.

*Gotta* is *slang* for *have got to*, and the latter is certainly not outdated. **We don't gotta go yet** is *terrible* English, and I suggest you do not get into the habit of saying something that will make you stand out as a poor speaker of English.

The list of modal verbs in use today is too broad to be addressed here, but you can learn them by reading. Reading personal blogs will give you an idea of how people *speak*. Reading articles will give you an idea of how people write today.

Comment: @Denis Kulagin - you may want to be up to date, but don't mistake that with bad English. Bad English is bad everywhere.

Comment: I would say that the GP's Alaskan teacher is doing him a great disservice.

Comment: To be pedantic in the extreme "We don't gotta go." is not terrible at all, and is the correct way to say things in particular varieties of English. It is very informal and would be incorrect in  Standard or published English. If you are learning English, you don't want to use that at all.

Comment: "that will make you stand out as a poor speaker of English" -- I would say, rather, that it makes you a good speaker of poor English, not a poor speaker of English. This kind of sentence structure and word choice is frequent among a certain category of native speakers, and you would likely fit right in without an eyeblink when speaking that way.

Comment: "We don't gotta go" is _extremely_ non-standard. Don't even _think_ of learning it! It might pass as the norm in some urban areas, but it will mark you as an illiterate boor. If your "teacher" insists on it, complain to his superiors and get him replaced with someone who teaches passable English. You don't want to end up speaking like that moron.

Answer (score 7):

**We must -> We have to**

These are both in common usage still - as a native speaker I would use "must" for emphasis, or to talk about things we should *consider* doing rather than absolutely are required to do.  For example

"We must get around to getting you that new dress..."

In this context "have to" wouldn't work.

Incidentally note the difference between two pronunciations of

"a list of things we have to do in our holidays"

pronounced [hafta] it is obligation, pronounced [havtu] it is a matter of possibility (What things do we have to do at Easter camp? We can go fishing, sailing, rock climbing, ...)

Another related one

"she was supposed to have killed him"

where the voicing on supposed makes the "thought" meaning and the devoicing the modal meaning.  The dropping of segments including voicing and differences in place of articulation (gotta, haft, sposta) is part of the entropic pressure on language, and it is those things that are becoming common frequent idioms that are most affected. It is the same process that lead to "the day" -> "to day" -> "to-day" -> "today" and "the morrow"... (note cognate Morgen in German still means both morning and tomorrow: in the morning = tomorrow).
Also I see the same affect in "one of" -> "one off" and "would have" -> "would've" -> "would of" -> "wouldf".

**May I come in? -> Do you mind if I come in?**

Actually I am not that polite or pedantic, and would say "Can I come in?" [knai kmin].
All are quite reasonable, your two are both polite, but my version is the most natural.

**We don't have to leave yet. -> We don't gotta go yet.**

I wouldn't say either, but would certainly use "have to" or "need to" rather than "don't gotta".  I would also say "I've got to go now" or "I have to go now" with almost equal likelihood, the former more informal but I could still say either in an important meeting or phone call (and have), as well as "I really must go now".

In terms of what is going on here, in every community, in every new generation, language is changing and new idioms are emerging (like the many uses of "like").  But the international media, and in particular movies and TV shows, means this spreads and we no longer have the insular effects to the same degree.

In practice, it is important to learn the new modals "hafta", "gotta", "sposta", "kinda", "like" if you want to fit in and sound natural/native.  The last two though I wouldn't use in a formal context.

Comment: you have to trade off the benefit of blending in and the risk of getting these idioms completely wrong. I had to make a list of banned words for my students, like "wanna" or "gotta" because foreigners would think them acceptable otherwise. I've had more than a dozen "wanna to" in my career, in formal exams. Yikes!

Comment: lets put it this way, you should be using "have to", "got to", "supposed to" as very frequent modals.  If you are speaking this *naturally* in a mid stress context (main stress on main verb) then there will be a tendency for your "to" to become vestigial. In the case of "want to" the /n/ is very close to the usual point of articulation of the /t/ which is thus easily assimilated.  There is nothing wrong with it sounding like "wanna" but you should always write the correct "to" form, and of course "wanna to" is just wrong (although "wanted to" will reduce to this).  Also it's "I've got to go".

Comment: Yes, the OP is very clear about a desire to clarify spoken/written context.

Comment: also worth clarifying formal/informal, e.g. letter/paper vs chat/sms, with email varying between these extremes according to its context.

Answer (score 4):

If someone says using 'gotta' as proper English, as a rule of thumb, I would recommend doing the exact opposite of everything they say. Gotta is phenomenally terrible English.

Seriously, every recommendation that you've listed is wrong.

- We must ➙ We have to

These are similar but they say different things. Many people will treat *must* as a stronger form of *have to*. They aren't simply interchangeable.

- May I come in? ➙ Do you mind if I come in?

This is just a completely different way of wording the same sentiment. If you were trying to pad the word count of your essay, or if you were trying to be extremely formal, then use the second. Otherwise, the first one is perfectly fine. Actually, it is better English than most people would use. Most people would say "**Can** I come in?". Using "May I" is technically more correct, but it isn't often used anymore.

I was always taught that 'Can I' is a question of capability. "Can I jump ten feet in the air?". Whereas 'May I' is a question of permission. Whenever someone would ask "Can I go to the bathroom?" one of my high school English teachers would always respond "Well of course you *can* go but, no, you may not go."

- We don't have to leave yet. ➙ We don't gotta go yet.

No. Just No. I don't know if words exist to describe exactly how bad that is.

In addition assuming the opposite of whatever this person recommends, I would advise against learning english from an American. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literacy_in_the_United_States) only 60% of Americans are literate. And of those who are literate, most can only read at the 7th grade level.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where you're seeing a figure of 60% in that article - even accepting the worst-case numbers, with the recognition that they've provided their own definition for what "literacy" means, they put the figure at somewhere between 65 and 85%.

Comment: Lazy rounding :)

Comment: WRT May/Do you mind: For any non-native speaker, I would **STRONGLY** recommend the former, specifically because of the expected response. The two questions have _opposite_ responses for the same answer; if you're permitted to perform the action, "May I..." will be answered with "Yes," while "Do you mind if I..." will be answered with "No." (And vice-versa.) This is a common stumbling block for exchange students to from all over the world coming to the US.

Comment: Prescriptively, *can* or *could* is fundamentally about ability and by extension capability, *may* or *might* about possibility and by extension permission, *do you mind* is about opinion and by extension preference.  In practice, all questions can be taken and answered as equivalent, and the answer would be whatever the person feels most appropriate e.g. if it is about smoking - I might say: "it is permitted, but I'd prefer if you didn't" (if my status was high enough) or "please go ahead" (even if I hate cigarette smoke but am at a status disadvantage). In all these cases, "please come in".

Answer (score 3):

> Is it true, and if so, to what extent?

An [axiom of communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_Principle) is to understand (expect and accept) a wide range of forms from other people.

- I'd agree with your teacher if he says that those second forms are often used instead of the first forms.
- I'd disagree with your teacher if he says that those first forms are "outdated" meaning obsolete or archaic (maybe they're uncommon in Alaska, I don't know, but they're still used elsewhere)

Forms like "will", "shall", "can", "must", "should", and "may" have distinct and precise meanings. They're used in [technical literature](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt), and are spoekn in [polite society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polite_society). Using them may mark you as, not only an English-speaker, but a well-educated one.

"We have to" and "Do you mind if" are also correct and polite.

"We don't gotta" is some form of [slang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang).

Slang is part of the language too: you need to be able to understand it, because some people will speak it. Because some people will speak it, you may want to be able to speak it too sometimes, if you want to try to [sound like you belong to that 'ingroup'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth).

Answer (score 0):

I would say your teacher's view ìs an oversimplification on school level. There is no way around knowing the handful of modal verbs as they are the verbs most frequently used. And, of course, you have to know their substitue forms.

Comment: I have to argue. In school, we are not being taught English, but some fixed snapshot of the English. And while we learn for 10 or more years, language changes severely. I only wish I can be up-to-date.

Comment: @DenisKulagin I do find it rather surprising however that your teacher wouldn't root for modal verbs. Seems like something that has always been dear to English teachers.

Comment: @Arlaud Pierre His a native speaker and that's it. He is teaching, but he definetelly doesn't have any special education. And that's what makes his lessons so interesting. Instead of learning some boring stuff and rope learning, he teaches us modern language and allows us to discuss day-related topics, which is more intresting than reading some dumm coursebooks.

Comment: It always was a torture at school, when you know English better than your teacher, but have to agree with he/she in order to avoid trouble and sustain teacher's authority. Now it's not the issue - you can't argue with native speaker about knowing language better.

Comment: @DenisKulagin Yes, but native English speakers can't agree with his English claims; heck, I'm not a native speaker myself and I surely disagree with it. "We don't gotta go yet" is bad English, I've heard "may I come in" a couple of time (also consider that it's in fact much shorter and easier to say that his alternative), and I see no problem with the verb "must". That being said, alternative are useful for other tenses, for instance the future of "I can come" is "I will be able to come".

Comment: @Arlaud Pierre That's is what called unconscious competence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_competence) - when I know something, but I can't explain why. If given two phrases of equal meaning in my native language I will unmistakably say which one is better for a specific situation. Why? Don't know, just my brain collected some statistics. That's all. The same for MUST: to his ear it sounds weird. That doesn't mean that for some british guy it sounds the same. Still we have "have to" as a compromise for both.

Comment: I have a more challenging dilemma, though. I am teaching English to my cousin and I will have to explain modal verbs to her one day. It's a riddle for me, how I should explain topic to her: british-flavoured, american-flavoured or just copy-paste some knowledge from the coursebook they use at school. Most likely I'll do the latter, which is quite sad.

Comment: @DenisKulagin: Why is it quite sad? When one starts learning a language, the most important thing is to get the basic right (which means something neither too formal nor too informal, as well as neither too long or complex) and avoid overwhelming the student with too much information. From this basic we can then build onto higher levels. My recommendation? Start with the 'flavour' your niece is learning and expand her horizons bit by bit.

Comment: @SaraCosta It's very complicated, actually. In my native language we have couple of words for have-to, should, must, ought to and so on. So it's pretty hard for beginner to wrap their heads around those differences. And it would be a real catastrophe, if someone will later say: "Forget everything you were taught at school. Real language is different..."

Comment: So my task here is to find golden middle, from which it would be easier to branch into different aspects of modern English. And, maybe more difficult, to explain, that what I am teaching her is not the absolute truth and it may vary.